# vue3 by vite hot replacement not work in homestead

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am new in Vite, I follow the [scaffolding-your-first-vite-project](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project) by

```sh
npm init @vitejs/app client --template vue
```

edit the default `package.json`

```json
{
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000",
    "build": "node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js build --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000",
    "serve": "node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js preview --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^1.2.2",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.5",
    "vite": "^2.3.4"
  }
}
```

then

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

everything works fine
[image: vue3+vite in homestead]

---

**But when I change the `components/HelloWorld.vue`, nothing happended, the hot module replacement didn't work**

I checked the `NODE_ENV` and change `package.json` like below:

```json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js cross-env NODE_ENV=development --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000",
```

But pages turn into blank and a lot of errors appeared in console.

How can I find out the issue?
Great thanks for anyone helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I fixed this by

1. replace the `@`/`~` in your `import()` with `./`/`../`

```js
✅ Do
import('./pages/index.vue')
❌Do not
import('@/pages/index.vue)
```

more detail: https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#limitations

2. passing `usePolling` to the `server.watch` options in the Vite config

```js
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  server: {
    watch: {
      usePolling: true
    }
  }
})
```

more detail: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1153#issuecomment-785467271

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `script`:

```sh
node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js cross-env NODE_ENV=development --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`cross-env` needs to be the primary command, so move it to the beginning:

```sh
cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000
```

But just so you're aware, `vite` by default sets `NODE_ENV` to `development`, so there's no need to do it yourself.